# Parsing array of an object in a library constructor

Tags: arduino-uno, c++, library, array, pointer

I am trying to develop an Arduino library that consists out of two classes. I want 'WayPointStack' to store an array of 'WPCommand', but I can't get it to work.

WayPointStack.h

```
#ifndef WayPointStack_h
#define WayPointStack_h

#include "Arduino.h"
#include "WPCommand.h"

class WayPointStack
{
  public:
    WayPointStack();
    WayPointStack(WPCommand* wp);
    WPCommand GetNextWP();
    WPCommand GetWP(int i);
    void AddWP(int target, int time);
    int SetWPPointer(int i);
    int GetLength();
  private:
    WPCommand* _wp;
    int pointer;
    int length;
};
#endif
```

WPCommand.h

```
#ifndef WPCommand_h
#define WPCommand_h

#include "Arduino.h"

class WPCommand
{
  public:
    WPCommand(int target, int time );
    WPCommand();
    int GetTarget();
    int GetTime();
    int LEFT;
    int RIGHT;
    int FORWARD;
    int BACKWARD;
    int STOP;
    int END;
  private:
    int _target;
    int _time;
};

#endif
```

Parts of WaypointStack.cpp

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "WayPointStack.h"
#include "WPCommand.h"

#define arrSize 100

WayPointStack::WayPointStack()
{
  _wp = new WPCommand[arrSize]; // should be enough, heap blabla
  length = 0;
  pointer = 0;
}

WayPointStack::WayPointStack(WPCommand[] wp)
{
    _wp = new WPCommand[arrSize]; // should be enough, heap blabla
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(wp), i++){
        _wp[i] = wp[i];
    }
    length = sizeof(wp);
    pointer = 0;
}
```

I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong with the pointers, but I don't know how to fix it. The first two errors are

```
WayPointStack.cpp:24:42: error: expected ',' or '...' before 'wp'
WayPointStack::WayPointStack(WPCommand[] wp)
```

and

```
WayPointStack.cpp:27:29: error: 'wp' was not declared in this scope
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(wp), i++){
```

I obviously have to use a pointer. This is all I know, so far.
Has someone an idea?

Comment: Arduino is not Java it is based on C++. Check the syntax for array/vectors and passing parameters by reference. Also check who to determine the number of elements in a vector. Sizeof() is the number of bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a C++, not Arduino question and should be asked on Stack Overflow.

In C/C++ the [] must be on variable name, not on type. `WPCommand wp[]` (it is the same as `WPCommand* wp`).

`sizeof` return size in bytes, not element count. send `length` as parameter

Dynamic memory allocation in MCU is not a good thing. You can have in `WayPointStack`

```
WPCommand _wp[arrSize]
```

Comment: Thank you. It reduced the error amount dramatically.